# WSO2 ESB: WARNING: EPRs are NULL. Transport configuration my be incorrect

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

When activating a proxy (with the Web UI), I always get following error message:

```
WARNING: EPRs are NULL. Transport configuration may be incorrect
```

But I just don't understand why and what it means?

[image]

The source of the proxy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="patient_toMPI_pJMS_qPatientToMPI" statistics="disable" trace="disable" transports="jms">
    <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">patient_qPatientToMPI</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ConnectionFactory">queueNonBlocking</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.DestinationType">queue</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
        <rules>
            <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
            <default>application/xml</default>
        </rules>
    </parameter>
    <target faultSequence="errorSequence">
        <inSequence>
            <log level="custom">
                <property name="Patient/toMPI" value="proxy (patient_toMPI_pJMS_qPatientToMPI) called"/>
            </log>
            <sequence key="patient_toMPI_sTransform"/>
        </inSequence>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

Comment: Can you share the proxy service source view? This usually means you have not exposed the service in any of the transports hence there are no endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has already been reported as a bug [here](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-1657). It will be resolved in future releases.

Comment: ok thanks. But does it have an influence on my active/deactivate? Or it just a bug of the user-interface?

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix :) Simply go to "Edit Data Service" and tick http and https on "Transport Settings" [image: Tick https and http (click image)]

Answer (score 0):

Are you logged in as the super tenant? If so you should not be getting this issue. Aforementioned bug, we experienced only in tenant-mode.
Please make sure, you have copied required (correct) client libraries into repository/components/lib directory in ESB to allow connection between the ESB and the JMS provider.

For eg: If the provider is active-mq, you need to copy following jar files.
activemq-core-xxx.jar AND geronimo-j2ee-management_xx_spec-xx.jar

Comment: Hi. Well both .jar are in the components/lib directory. Strange is that it occurs only sometimes - not for all proxies.

Comment: If you are using activemq, then you need to copy 3 jar files from activemq lib to repository/components/lib. Those are geronimo-j2ee-management_XX_spec-XX.jar, geronimo-jms_xx_spec-xx.jar and activemq-core-xx.jar.